# How to fit a sine function from one range to another?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to fit a sine wave that spans the usual y-direction range from -1 to 1 into a range from 3 to 13 (for instance). Is there a simple command that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a function to do this, just some basic algebra.

First, you want to get the midline of the transformed sine wave by averaging your intended upper and lower bounds. In your example, it's 8 because `(3+16)/2 = 8`.

Next, you're going to want to find the amplitude of the transformed sine wave. You can do this by subtracting the midline from the upper bound. In your example, it's `5` because `13-8 = 5`.

With these values, you just need to multiply the output of the sine function by your amplitude and then add the midline. In your example, you'd want to use `5*sin(x)+8`. If you want to proof-check this, just plug it into Desmos or any other graphing calculator.

Your original question didn't specify a language, but here's an example in Python that can be easily translated into any other language:

```py
import math

def transformedSine(upper, lower, input):
    midline = (upper + lower) / 2
    return (upper-midline) * math.sin(input) + midline;
```